# Is there any way to output logs using log4js on Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, log4js-node

I'm using GCP's cloud function. What I want to achieve is to output logs by log4js.

I know and have tried that using console.xxx() works well.

Environment:
 - Google Cloud Functions
 - Functions-framework
 - nodejs10 as Runtime

**logger.js**

```
const log4js = require('log4js');

const logger = exports = module.exports = {};

log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    out: { type: 'console' },
    trail: {
      type: 'dateFile',
      filename: './logs/trail',
      pattern: '-yyyy-MMdd-hh.log',
      alwaysIncludePattern: true
    }
  },
  categories: {
    default: { appenders: [ 'out' ], level: 'info' },
    trail: { appenders: [ 'trail' ], level: 'DEBUG' }
  }
})

logger.trail = log4js.getLogger('trail')
```

**index.js**

```
const { logger } = require('./logger');

exports.spTest = (pubSubEvent, context) => {
  console.log('console.log should appear'); // => properly logged
  logger.trail.error('logger should appear'); => doesn't show up
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the oficial documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/basic-concepts):

> Cloud Logging is part of the Google Cloud's operations suite of
>   products in Google Cloud. It includes storage for logs, a user
>   interface called the Logs Viewer, and an API to manage logs
>   programmatically.

Also [Custom StackDriver logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs)

> Cloud Functions logs are backed by StackDriver Logging. You can use
>   the StackDriver Logging library for Node.js to log events with
>   structured data, enabling easier analysis and monitoring.

```
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');

// ...

// Instantiate the StackDriver Logging SDK. The project ID will
// be automatically inferred from the Cloud Functions environment.
const logging = new Logging();
const log = logging.log('my-custom-log-name');

// This metadata is attached to each log entry. This specifies a fake
// Cloud Function called 'Custom Metrics' in order to make your custom
// log entries appear in the Cloud Functions logs viewer.
const METADATA = {
  resource: {
    type: 'cloud_function',
    labels: {
      function_name: 'CustomMetrics',
      region: 'us-central1'
    }
  }
};

// ...

// Data to write to the log. This can be a JSON object with any properties
// of the event you want to record.
const data = {
  event: 'my-event',
  value: 'foo-bar-baz',

  // Optional 'message' property will show up in the Firebase
  // console and other human-readable logging surfaces
  message: 'my-event: foo-bar-baz'
};

// Write to the log. The log.write() call returns a Promise if you want to
// make sure that the log was written successfully.
const entry = log.entry(METADATA, data);
log.write(entry);index.js
```

Therefore, I do not think you can use  log4js on Cloud Functions.

Comment: Ah still we can manage them by this SDK, that's more than enough! Actually this is what I need. I appreciate that!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it for better visibility for the community.